# How do I fetch json data in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-controller

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts I have to fetch data from this link and display it in my browser. In Javascript I used to do it using XMLHttpRequest and then parse it using JSON.parse(response). Is there a way I can achieve something similar in angularjs. Thank you

Comment: google "angularjs + rest github sample" download a project and try. This will be easiest :)

Comment: Thanks it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can review this link [angular http get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

**sample**

```
 $http({
     method: 'GET',
       url: '/someUrl'
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
/ / called asynchronously if an error occurs
   // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Comment: It's usually worth pointing out to beginners that the response data is in `response.data`